# Using pattern to find all words between. What if my boundaries contain characters other than letters?

Tags: java, twitter

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\bSTARTTEXTHERE\\b)(.*?)(\\bENDTEXTHERE\\b)");
```

Hey guys I am having trouble. I am using a crude work around for bascially learning purposes to get all website data using URLConnection and InputStream. converting all that to a string using this

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;

        // read each line and write to System.out
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            website += line;
        }
```

and then wanting to do a simple pattern / matcher task to find all words (tweets in this case) between `label-part="0">` and  `</p></div>`

I have found that all tweets on a page are always contained between these quotes and nothing else on the page has these quotes so in theory I should return the string which is the tweet. example : lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">this is a test tweet< /p>  However this code does not work

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\bdata-aria-label-part="0">\\b)(.*?)(\\b</p></div>\\b)");
```

The `"0"` is what is throwing the error. I have tried brackets and quotes and tried to make a string which that line of text but it only accepts words to my knowledge. Is this a limitation of the matcher class? I have tired to do some research here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html However I am quite new to coding and am finding it difficult to figure it out. I feel there has to be some way to take what you put in those areas as almost a string of characters

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Edit 
I actually tried escaped quotes straight after posting the question however that didn't work. I have tried normal words and they work.

Comment: Maybe escape the quotes inside with backslash?

Comment: I actually tried escaped quotes straight after posting the question however that didn't work. I have tried normal words and they work.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("data-aria-label-part=\"0\">(.*?)</p></div>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(website);
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(matches);
            matches.remove(m.group(1));
        }
```